# What exactly does each ZSTD compression level do?

Tags: compression, zstd, folly

The ZSTD compression library by Facebook offers over 19 compression levels, but sometimes some seem to have more effect on overall compression efficiency and compression time than others.

What exactly is the difference between, for e.g., level 5 and level 6 in terms of the specific parameters being set?

For reference: https://facebook.github.io/zstd/zstd_manual.html

Comment: It's open source, have a look at the implementation: https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/lib/compress/clevels.h#L25 and https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/lib/zstd.h#L1291